# Map Core Data model object to make calculations

Tags: arrays, swift, function, loops, core-data

I am trying to iterate through a Core Data model object and make calculations as follow. I can't figure out the `for - in` loops tho. Here every value is multiplied by every amount so the `append` and `total` are wrong. I only need each `value` to be multiplied to it's corresponding `amount` (for example `bitcoin` with `1.00000000`).

```
func updateWalletLabel() {

    var values : [Double] = []

    guard let items : [CryptosMO] = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() else { return }

    let codes = items.map { $0.code! }
    let amounts = items.map { $0.amount! }

    print(codes) // ["bitcoin", "litecoin"]
    print(amounts) // ["1.00000000", "2.00000000"]
    // please note these values are in correct order (x1 bitcoin, x2 litecoin)

    for code in codes {
        for amount in amounts {

            let convertedAmount = Double(amount)!

            let crypto = code
            guard let price = CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[crypto] else { return }

            let calculation = price * convertedAmount
            values.append(calculation)
        }
    }

    let total = values.reduce(0.0, { $0 + Double($1) } )

    print("VALUES", values) // [7460.22, 14920.44, 142.68, 285.36] (need [7460.22, 285.36])
    print("TOTAL:", total) // 22808.7 (need 7745.58)
}
```

How can I modify my `for-in` loops here so the calculations are only happening once for each array item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two arrays of the same length and in the same order, you can use Swift's `zip` function to combine the two into an array of tuples. In that case, your loop would change to

```
for (code, amount) in zip(codes, amounts) {
    // Your calculation
}
```

See also the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip)

Comment: Swift is amazing!